# Organising vim plugins into separate directories

Tags: vim

Is it possible to place each of my vim plugins in a separate directory within my `~/.vim` directory?

Unpacking everything into the same place seems kind of messy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want pathogen.vim.  You can find it at http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332 or http://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen

Answer (score 1):

See

```
help vimfiles
```

Plugins usually go into

```
.../vimfiles/plugins
```

directory, but if you put them in subdirectories of *plugins* there will be no problem. Vim will load them all.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me (I'm running MacVIM) unless I add each plugin directory to the runtimepath manually.

Comment: ... but editing the runtimepath gets me what i want anyway, so thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Interesting. On Win and *nix works without that. Unfortunatelly, I don't have access to a Mac so I couldn't check it on that. But, as long as the problem is solved ... :)

Comment: Of course, that doesn't work for plugins that have an autoload script.

Comment: @graywh ... Mea culpa ! 'tis true !